System Watchers never die
I am trying to monitor multiple file locations and then push files that have changed to other locations based on a config text file. This works great! The file monitoring works, and the files get moved to their destinations, but if I restart the service, or if I am in PowerShell and running it through the command line it spawns new system watchers but never kills the existing ones.
Only way they die is if I am in PowerShell and close out of it completely, but if I have the service running, they never seem to die until I restart the computer. I have used NSSM to create the PowerShell service and that of course works great. I have used NSSM hundreds of times.
Bellow is the code. I am attempting to clean up my previous watchers at the beginning and end of the running process, but the file changes and it attempts to move the file multiple times...
# Read config.txt file and process each line
$configFile = "Y:\config.txt"
$configLines = Get-Content -Path $configFile
$filter = '*.*'
$continueLoop = $true  # Control variable for the while loop

# List to store FileSystemWatchers and their SourceIdentifiers for cleanup
$watchers = @()

# Trap to handle Ctrl + C (PipelineStoppedException)
trap [System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException] {
    Write-Host "`nCtrl + C pressed. Exiting..."
    $continueLoop = $false
    break
}
function Cleanup-ExistingEvents {
    Write-Host "Cleaning up existing event subscribers and jobs..."

    # Step 1: Unregister existing event subscribers
    $existingSubscribers = Get-EventSubscriber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    foreach ($subscriber in $existingSubscribers) {
        if ($subscriber.SourceIdentifier -like 'FileChanged_*') {
            Write-Host "Removing existing event with SourceIdentifier: $($subscriber.SourceIdentifier)"
            try {
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $subscriber.SourceIdentifier -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier $subscriber.SourceIdentifier -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "Failed to remove event with SourceIdentifier: $($subscriber.SourceIdentifier)"
            }
        }
    }

    # Step 2: Dispose of watchers before cleaning up jobs
    if ($Global:watchers) {
        foreach ($watcherInfo in $Global:watchers) {
            try {
                Write-Host "Disposing watcher for SourceIdentifier: $($watcherInfo.SourceIdentifier)"
                $watcherInfo.Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
                $watcherInfo.Watcher.Dispose()
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "Failed to dispose watcher for: $($watcherInfo.SourceIdentifier)"
            }
        }
        $Global:watchers = @()
    }

    # Step 3: Stop and remove lingering jobs
    $existingJobs = Get-Job -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    foreach ($job in $existingJobs) {
        if ($job.Name -like 'FileChanged_*') {
            Write-Host "Stopping job: $($job.Name)"
            try {
                Stop-Job -Name $job.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Receive-Job -Name $job.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
                Remove-Job -Name $job.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning "Failed to stop or remove job: $($job.Name)"
            }
        }
    }

    # Step 4: Final verification and cleanup
    $remainingJobs = Get-Job -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'FileChanged_*' }
    if ($remainingJobs) {
        Write-Warning "Some jobs are still lingering:"
        $remainingJobs | Format-Table -AutoSize

        # Attempt final cleanup in a new PowerShell session
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            Get-Job -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
                Stop-Job -Id $_.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                Remove-Job -Id $_.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }
        } | Wait-Job
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "All jobs and event subscribers cleaned up."
    }
}

# Perform the cleanup before starting new watchers
Cleanup-ExistingEvents

# Create FileSystemWatchers based on config lines
$index = 0
foreach ($line in $configLines) {
    # Split the line into variables
    $splitLine = $line -split '\|'
    $pod = $splitLine[0]
    $sourceFolder = $splitLine[1]
    $sourceFile = $splitLine[2]
    $destinationPath = $splitLine[3]

    # Create a FileSystemWatcher to monitor file changes in the specified source folder
    $fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $sourceFolder, $filter -Property @{
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        NotifyFilter          = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
    }

    # Define a unique SourceIdentifier for each FileSystemWatcher
    $sourceIdentifier = "FileChanged_$index"
    $index++

    # Register the event and store it for cleanup
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Changed -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier -Action {
        $sourceFolderCopy = $Event.MessageData.sourceFolderCopy
        $sourceFileCopy = $Event.MessageData.sourceFileCopy
        $destinationPathCopy = $Event.MessageData.destinationPathCopy

        Write-Host "$sourceFolderCopy , $sourceFileCopy , $destinationPathCopy"
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Host "File $($changeType): $name at $timeStamp"

        if ($changeType -eq 'Changed' -and $name -eq $sourceFileCopy) {
            $SourceDriveLetter = 'S'
            New-PSDrive -Name $SourceDriveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $sourceFolderCopy

            $DestinationDriveLetter = 'P'
            $pass = "ridge" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
            $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('Blue', $pass)
            New-PSDrive -Name $DestinationDriveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $destinationPathCopy -Credential $cred

            Copy-Item "$($SourceDriveLetter):\$($sourceFileCopy)" "$($DestinationDriveLetter):\$($sourceFileCopy)"

            Remove-PSDrive -Name $SourceDriveLetter
            Remove-PSDrive -Name $DestinationDriveLetter
        }
    } -MessageData @{ sourceFolderCopy = $sourceFolder; sourceFileCopy = $sourceFile; destinationPathCopy = $destinationPath }

    # Store the watcher for cleanup later
    $watchers += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Watcher          = $fsw
        SourceIdentifier = $sourceIdentifier
    }

    # Start monitoring the folder
    $fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
}

try {
    # Keep the script running, but exit if an exception occurs or Ctrl + C is pressed
    while ($continueLoop) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred: $_"
    $continueLoop = $false
}
finally {
    # Ensure cleanup of resources on script exit
    Write-Host "`nCleaning up resources..."

    foreach ($watcherInfo in $watchers) {
        # Unregister the event and dispose of the watcher
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $watcherInfo.SourceIdentifier -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $watcherInfo.Watcher.Dispose()
    }
    Cleanup-ExistingEvents
    Write-Host "Resources and events cleaned up. Exiting."
 
}





Have your debugging efforts provided any clues as to where the program flow is misbehaving?
